# US traffic by day in Google Analytics. Is it possible and how?

Tags: google-analytics

How can I view traffic from specific country day by day ? I mean I would like to get report of US traffic from specific time frame by day. e.g US traffic starting from 1st October 2010 to 31th October 2010 day by day.

Is this possible in google analytics ? and if so... how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a big fan of Advanced segments because they allow you to apply the segment to any report. To create one for visitors from the United States you would click the "Advanced Segments" dropdown on the top right above the date range selector. Select create new advanced segment add country/territory as the dimension make the settings "matches exactly" and "United States" then name your segment and save it. Now you can look at any report you want, and to see the data just from that segment you select it in the dropdown. This even gives you the option to compare segments (IE you can see how visitors from the Untied States compare to all the visits etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Under the map overlay section click view report, after the new page loads, select United States from the list, if available. The from the date field in the upper right corner select the dates you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for Creating Custom Reports in Google Analytics which will help you with creating custom reports. You may require to use Pageviews, unique visitors as metrices & Continent,monthly, hour of the day respectively as dimensions and subdimensions to create your required report.